# Sci-fi movie about good and evil android on space ship

Tags: story-identification, cyborg, androids

I'm searching for a Sci-Fi movie I saw in my childhood (late 80s - early 90s). The movie was about a crew on a spaceship with two similar looking androids or robots; one evil trying to kill the crew and one good fighting to save the crew.

The Robots had a similar head shape like the Human Helmets from Battlestar Galactica and some kind of green color in their face.

There was this special scene i can remember where they tried to reach a save room but one human didn't made it throu the closing door and his face was slammed against the glass of the door by the robot while the other human couldn't help

Comment: Did they look human, or kind of like trashcans with faces (eg, Black Hole)

Comment: This is far to vague and will likely get closed, take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Androids was the wrong word i think.. cause they didn't look human, more then robots. As i can remember they had some green colored face

Comment: There was this special scene i can remember where they tried to reach a saver room but one human didn't made it throu the closing door and his face was slammed against the glass in the door by the robot and the other human couldn't help

Comment: no no.. no star trek episode, it was an complete movie

Comment: Ok, that may filter it out as I have no recollection of that occurring. Also these guys had, one right side of the face was black, the left side what white, the other had, the right side of the face white and the left side was black.

Comment: Do you know the helmets the humans had worn in Battlestar Galactica? The Robots had a similar head shape.. as i can remember

Comment: You mean the original one with the red eye

Comment: no.. the human one

Comment: you mean the cylon

Comment: Like these? (Trying to make sure your talking about the original and not the remake) https://www.google.com/search?q=Battlestar+galactica+helmets&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2humw5PLTAhVH4mMKHTEHDXwQ7AkIOg&biw=1229&bih=638

Comment: the Black Hole isn't the movie.. these robots looking way to funny :D

Comment: yes.. thats the right one

Comment: Here try this list and see if anything prompts more memory "The 100 Greatest Movie Robots of All Time" - https://www.pastemagazine.com/articles/2015/11/the-100-greatest-movie-robots-of-all-time.html?a=1

Comment: This is the closest I can get to your description and time http://www.tvacres.com/images/robots_twiki.jpg It is from a series Buck Rodgers but past that it will take a more indepth search. Good luck.

Comment: @AxelF Please [edit] your question with the details you've described in the comments. Comments are meant to be temporary and not everyone will see them -- if you want others to see the additional details you need to put them in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be the Doctor Who serial "**The Robots of Death**"? This is what the robots looked like:

[image]

Green faces, check.

Evil robots trying to kill the crew, check.

Good robots trying to save the crew, check.

They vaguely look like the helmets from Battlestar Galactica, half a check.

Comment: Very similar but still not the movie i'm searching for :/

Comment: But thanks a lot for your comment

Answer (score 5):

Could it be [The Black Hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Hole) (1979)?

USS *Palomino* encounters a long-lost and apparently abandoned ship stuck mysteriously surviving near a black hole. On board they find Dr. Hans Reinhardt and his menacing-looking robot Maximilian (who looks a bit like an original Cylon), along with other robots and masked servants.[image: Menacing red robot]

The *Palomino* crew have a robot companion which finds a battered-looking earlier model of itself and which later helps them fight Reinhardt's minions.[image: Palomino crew and robot]

More minion bots.
[image: More minion bots]

Missing the green about the face, though...

Comment: yeah.. the green faces are missing.. those movies look more like 60s and 70s to me. the movie im searching for has this 80s style

Answer (score 4):

Could it be [*Starship* (1984)](https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/94502-starship)? (It was also called "Lorca and the Outlaws" and "2084".)

Here is the TMDb synopsis:

> Jowitt, a mercenary without recluse institutes a totalitarian regime in a small mining city of an arid planet, Ordessa, helped in that by androids incapable of any emotion. The young Lorca and his android professor, Kid, are both in this tended situation. To find the liberty, they must at any costs seize a spaceship, the "Red Star", but they quickly have to face an android killer...

Here is an image of one of the androids:

[image: Android from "Starship"/"Lorca and the Outlaws"/"2084" (1984)]

I think that jibes with the description.

The entire film appears to be on YouTube:

I think the scene described in the question is at around 1:20:00 on that YouTube video.

Comment: You are awesome!!! That's the movie.. thanks for your help mate :D